# Regex - select words that aren't totally or partly matched

Tags: regex

The string in target: `This is a new pen.`

My goal is to turn the above string into `This is a __ __.` with JavaScript like:

```
const str = "This is a new pen." 
const newStr = str.replace(/[^this |is |a |an |the |are |.\s]+/ig, ' __ ').trim()
```

Sadly, the Regex used above was wrong, for it output `This is a ne __ __ en.` Because "an" and "the" were included in the Regex.

How may I reach the goal and still keep "an" and "the" in the Regex?

---

Edited:

I modified the original string 
to test the effect of `an`, `and`, `that` and `'s`, besides `a`, `this`, `the`, etc.:

```
const str = "This is a new pen and that's an old business book."
const newStr = str.replace(/[^this |is |\'s |and |that |a |an |the |are |.\s]+/ig, ' __ ').trim()
```

So the Regex is longer now but still problematic. An ideal outcome should be `This is a __ __ and that's an __ __ __.`

Comment: That regex is not doing what you expect.  Square brackets make a character set; the ordering of characters within the set doesn't matter.

Comment: @jasonharper I'm really not good at regex. The square brackets were added in order to bring out `^`'s effect which was to **not** select.

Comment: @sijane I've heavily updated my answer and am now done, I don't know if you get notifications but you might want to check it out. Please tell me if it doesn't suit your needs about apostrophes, I might have some time to improve it if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a more generic solution, you will want to craft a regex from an array of keywords :

```
const keywordsList = ["this", "is", "his", ... ];
const pattern = new RegExp("\\b(?!(?:" + keywordsList.join("|") + ")\\b)\\w+", "gi");

const newStr = str.replace(pattern, '__').trim();
```

It crafts a regex of the form `(?!\b(?:word1|word2|word3)\b)\w+` which matches a full word that isn't one of the specified keywords.

It could be nicely wrapped in a function :

```
function hideWords(input, preservedWords, mask="__") {
    const pattern = new RegExp("\\b(?!(?:" + preservedWords.join("|") + ")\\b)\\w+", "gi");
    return input.replace(pattern, mask);
}
```

Depending on what you want to do about contractions, it could work out of the box. Since it seems like you never want to have them replaced, just add each part of the contraction to your keyword list (I'm assuming your text shouldn't contain these letters alone in other contexts) :

```js
hideWords("This's what you'd've done!", ["this", "what", "you", "is", "his", "s", "d", "ve"]);
// This's what you'd've __!

hideWords("This is a new pen and that's an old business book.", ["this", "is", "s", "and", "that", "a", "an", "the", "are"]);
// This is a __ __ and that's an __ __ __.
```

It currently can replace parts of contractions, but not the whole thing with the apostrophe :

```js
hideWords("This'll do.", ["this", "do"]);
//This'__ do.

hideWords("This'll do.", ["do"]);
// __'__ do.
```

If this doesn't suit you, you at least need to replace the `\w` part of the regex with something that includes `'` and rework the word-boundaries. Since I'm not sure this is relevant to your interest I won't bother researching it for now.

Comment: @AbdulHameed Probably not, I had not seen the edit. Thanks for notifying me, I'll try to fix it :)

Comment: @AbdulHameed turns out it does when configured to, at least for OP's specific example.

Comment: Thanks for notifying me. I just finished testing your generous code and it's working smoothly now. I also thumbed up your answer just my present reputation is too low to make it appear; it will be there later I think. Thanks again.

Comment: @sijane you're welcome, it was an interesting question !

Answer (score 2):

try this regex `(?:(?!this |is |his |a |an |the |s |\s|\.).)+` with `gi` modifiers.

it lists all sorts of combinations of the word you want to not match `(this--> this,his, is,s )`

you can find the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/LFZ2Q9/1)

**UPDATE**:

try the new regex :

`\b(?!this\b|is\b|a\b|and\b|that\b|the\b|\s|an\b|s\b|\').+?(?=\s|\.)`

it excludes the words `this,is,,a,and,that,the,an,',s` and selects all other words.

to exclude `'s` i had to right one more negative lookahead and eliminate them.

you can try the full demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/nuNSBB/2)

Comment: it will work correctly only for your example. not for every case. for every case, i need more test cases of positive and negative results to write a regex

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Just I noticed a problem. If there were words in the target string like `hiss`, they would show partially rather than the whole words. Besides this, it seems I can't add some similarities like `|and` in the regex, for `and` in the string will be partially replaced too.

Comment: list more test cases in your question. then only solution can be obtained.

Comment: @AbdulHameed you should add word boundaries in order to avoid accidental partial matchs, e.g. the `his` of `history` in `this is history`.

Comment: @AbdulHameed Thank you for your generous solution from which I've learn ed something new about Regex. I thumbed up your answer as well and it should be appeared somedays later.